# Modificar ancho de código de barras ZPL

Tags: código-de-barras

tengo una duda y he estado tratando de resolverla pero esta es la primera vez que veo ZPL entonces debo hacer una etiqueta de 10 cm de ancho por 5 cm de alto. Ya la hice pero mi problema radica en que debo adaptar la barra al ancho de mi etiqueta, usando un visualizador de zpl (usé laberaly) y así es como veo mi etiqueta

```
^XA

^CFA,23
^FO7,20^FDMateria Prima: LADYGEX COM 21+7 MMED BE MYL^FS
^FO7,50^FDCodigo: 31183^FS
^FO7,80^FDLote: 0000000001^FS
^FO7,110^FDFecha Trasvasije: 11.06.2019^FS
^FO7,140^FDCantidad trasvasijada: 70,000^FS
^FO7,170^FDFecha de vencimiento: 30.01.2020^FS

^BY7,4,200
^FO7,200^BCN,150,Y,N,N
^FD (01)31183(10)0000000001^FS

^XZ
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si aumentan el ancho verán que mi código de barras es demasiado largo con respecto a lo que me exigen de anchura (10cm) , hay alguna etiqueta que maneje esto ?

Answer (score 0):

Con el `BY` puedes ajustar el ancho:

```
^FO110,55^BY1^BCN,100,N,N^SN A0003 123 ,1,Y^FS
```